# Protecting data in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a elastic search engine running locally with an index which contains data from Multiple customers.  When a customer makes a query, is there a way to dynamically add Customer Id in the filtering criteria so a customer cannot access the records from other customers.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can achieve that using [filtered aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html#filtered). So you'd create one alias per customer like this:

```
POST /_aliases
{
    "actions" : [
        {
            "add" : {
                 "index" : "customer_index",
                 "alias" : "customer_1234",
                 "filter" : { "term" : { "customer_id" : "1234" } }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Then your customer can simply query the alias `customer_1234` and only his data is going to come back.

Comment: While this will generally work, be aware that it allows side channel attacks because of the way how TF/IDF and BM25 work: https://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~davidcash/sp17stress.pdf

Comment: @xeraa Of course, this is not the *right* way to protect data. If security is a real concern, you should go with either [XPack Security](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/authorization.html) or an equivalent open-source alternative such as [SearchGuard](https://docs.search-guard.com/latest/document-level-security)

Comment: IMO the side channel attack works even if you are using X-Pack security. Term statistics are not filtered, so sharing an index just doesn't offer good isolation.

Comment: Thank you for the responses.  But cannot client cannot guess the aliases?  The Kibana/Xpack security controls access at the "Service Level".  Not sure if there is a way to define user name password at alias level?  The other option is hide Elastic Search Rest Service behind a custom service which implements Custom Security options.  However, in that case, we may not have search flexibility.

Comment: `customer_1234` was just an example, you could use an UUID instead as the alias name.